# Symfony2 select choice ajax

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I haven't found any comprehensive answer at the moment ..
I would like to learn how to change a select option based on the choices of another select.
eg.
Category One-to-Many SubCategory

I select an option from the Category and SubCategory select content changes.
Could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the end I decided to use this method:
javascript:

```
$('select[name*="[category][category]"]').prop('selected', true).change(function(){
             var Id =  $(this).val();          
             var url = Routing.generate('route_to_retrieve_subcategory');

            $.post(url, 
            { 'idCat': Id  
            }, function(results){
                var sub = $('select[name*="[category][category]"]').parent().find('select[name*="[subCategory][]"]');
                sub.empty();
                $.each(results , function(key, value) { 
                    sub
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value.id)
                    .text(value.subCategory)); 
                });

       });
    });
```

controller:

```
public function getSubcategoryAction(Request $request)
{
      $Id = $request->get('idCat');
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $entities = $em->getRepository('MyBusinessBundle:SubCategories')->findSubCategories($Id);
      $output = array();
      foreach ($entities as $member) {
          $output[] = array(
              'id' => $member->getId(),
              'subCategory' => $member->getSubCategory(),
          );
      }

      $response = new Response();
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      $response->setContent(json_encode($output));
      return $response;
}
```

route:

```
route_to_retrieve_subcategory:
pattern: /route_to_retrieve_subcategory
defaults: { _controller: "MyBusinessBundle:ajax:getSubcategory" }
options:
    expose: true
```

I prefer not to pass parameters through the course, I feel that it does not make sense!

A big thank you to shrujan shetty for the inspiration.

Comment: an argument to use parameters is that it becomes easily possible to test the ajax url in your browser and see what json output is sent back. Excellent solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to use the routing url to pass the control to the action using jquery
eg

```
              $('# category id').change(function(){
                 var Id =  $('#category id').val();          
                 var url = Routing.generate('route_to_retrieve_subcategory', { 'Id': Id  });

                $.post(url, 
                { 'Id': Id  
                },function(data){
                  $('#subcategoryId').html(data);
                 },"text");
            }
        });
```

In controller

```
/**
     * @Route("subcategory/{Id}",name="route_to_retrieve_subcategory" )
     * @Template()
     */
    public function getSubcategoryAction($Id)
    {
          //code
         return new Response($subcategoryList, 200);


    }
```

Note:
the route must be listed in routing.yml file

```
route_to_retrieve_subcategory:
    pattern: /route_to_retrieve_subcategory/{Id}
    defaults: {_controller: YourBundle:YourController:getSubcategory}
    options:
        expose: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
But for the rest as I do? I create a new select field generated by a query?
why put the Id parameter on the route? is not the same use as the "data" parameter of the method $.ajax? 
Would not it be better to just change the options of the select, rather than replace the entire select?